# Reset input-field when click outside the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, reset

I have the following code that enables inline editing

```
$('.edit_td').click(function() {
    resetEditedCells(); 
    $(this).addClass('active').html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '">');
});

function resetEditedCells() {
        $('.edit_td.active').html(function() {
        return $(this).find('input').val();
    });
}
```

This works fine when switching from td to td. But when I click anywhere else, outside the table, I want the input fields, to transform back to the regular tds.

Ive tried like this:

```
$(document).on('blur', function(e) {
    if($('.edit_td').hasClass('active')) {
        $('.active').remove();
    } else {
        alert("false");
    }

});
```

The .blur() is not triggered. Anyone?

Comment: Do you know you are bluring the document itself? Not the edit field...

Comment: maybe your are looking for `$(this).removeClass('active').empty().text(original_text);`

Comment: Try `$('input').on('blur'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use click event instead of blur:

```
$(document).click(function() {
 if($('.edit_td').hasClass('active')) {
     $('.active').remove();
 } else {
     alert("false");
}});
```

also modify td click event to  `stopPropagation`:

```
$('.edit_td').click(function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
 resetEditedCells(); 
 $(this).addClass('active').html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).html() + '">');
});
```

Comment: That don't work. When I click on the td, the click on the document is fired, and the td is not transformed to an input field. When you first click on a td, the td should transform to an input field. When you click outside the table itselfe, the input-field should reset to an td.

Comment: It's better to bind a blur event directly on the field. If you bind to the document, the function will be called anytime the webpage is clicked. This uses needless processing power.

Comment: @user500468: have you added  stopPropagation in td click event??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: Thank you. But how can I capture the value of the input-field before removing it? 

EDIT: Never mind. I solved it :)

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: How can I restore the the td and it's value when I have removed the class? When I click outside the element, the content inside the td is removed.

Comment: Instead of removing, you should hide `$('.active')` this will allow you to retain the value later on.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: When I write $('.active').hide(), the content of the TD is still lost. I want the value of the td to appear back.

Comment: `hide()` should not remove the content. on showing back the td. its content should reappear

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to replace the code you have

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var edit_td = $(e.target).closest('.edit_td');

    if ( edit_td.length > 0 ) {

        resetEditedCells(); 
        edit_td.addClass('active')
               .html('<input type="text" value="' + edit_td.html() + '">');

    }else{

        $('.edit_td.active').removeClass('active').empty();

    }
});
```

This uses `closest()` to determine if the click originated from inside or outside a TD.

Comment: that's how i usually do it.

Answer (score 0):

try this js code where edit_td class applied to every td and active class is there on a active td and blur function is bind to the td having "edit_td" and "active" class applied on them.

```
$('.edit_td.active').on('blur', function(e) {
       $('.active').remove();
    });
```

Comment: Add some explanation to code so that it is helpful to OP

Comment: @CasperSky explanation added.